# How to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: .net, string, iconvertible

Can't seem to find out how to make values from a array appear in a label..

```
sthlmLbl.Text += String.Format(" {0} grader celcius ({1} \x00b0F)", tempsisar[0], ((Convert.ToInt32(value) * (9 / 5)) + 32));
```

gives the exception

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

Cant find a good answer to this, and since I'm working on a windows forms app I just cant inherit IConvertible either...

Comment: So what is in value, error indicates a string[]...

Comment: Its for a property and value is a string[], yes.

Comment: Nevermind this, it is solved. The Convert.ToInt32(value) did use the index of value, so it crashed, and the exception error displayed a different error than that...so I couldn't find it.